# Raspberry pi: Associate "screen" and Systemd to auto-start a minecraft server at pi's start

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, systemd, raspberry-pi4, minecraft-forge

I'm new in raspberry pi programming, and i want to be able to launch a minecraft server at the start of the pi.

For that, I've already loocked at Systemd files and screen command.

I manage to make them work separately, but not together, it's why I'm looking for help there.

Firstly, I'm using a Raspberry pi 4 4Go with raspbian v10, and forge 1.12.2 with java 8.
I did a .sh file to launch easier the server:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S mcserver -dm java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar /home/pi/MinecraftServer/server/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui
```

When I run the file, the server start perfectly in a socket as I want.

Secondly, I have a systemd file (auto-run-server.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto run mc server
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/MinecraftServer/server/minecraft.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I execute the service, nothing is happening, the status of the service shows a sucess, but there is nothing in screens (screen -list)

And when i replace the `ExecStart` value by

`ExecStart=java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar /home/pi/MinecraftServer/server/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui`

The server starts, but the problem is that I want to access to a terminal to run commands in minecraft server, and i didn't find solution to access from there.
( It's why I want to create a "screen" )

I'm fully open to your answers, even if they don't use "screen", as long as I can access to a server terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running screen from the same account that systemd uses ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Marged, but I've only one account on the pi, the one by defaults.

Comment: You only use `root` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the follow `systemd` unit for testing:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/tmp/screentest.sh
```

And this `screentest.sh` shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -S mcserver -dm sh -c 'while :; do date; sleep 5; done'
```

If I start the service (`systemctl start screentest`) and then run `systemctl status screentest`, I see:

```
● screentest.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/screentest.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The problem here is that the `screen` command exits immediately when running with `-d`, so `systemd` believes the command has completed and cleans everything up by removing any additional processes spawned by the service.

We can tell `systemd` that the service spawns a child and exits by setting the service type to `forking`:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/tmp/screentest.sh
```

With this change in place, after starting the service we see:

```
● screentest.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/screentest.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-01-10 09:58:11 EST; 4s ago
  Process: 14461 ExecStart=/tmp/screentest.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14463 (screen)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/screentest.service
           ├─14463 SCREEN -S mcserver -dm sh -c while :; do date; sleep 5; done
           ├─14464 sh -c while :; do date; sleep 5; done
           └─14466 sleep 5
```

And `screen -list` shows:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/systemd/system# screen -list
There is a screen on:
        14612.mcserver  (01/10/2021 10:01:55 AM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.
```

Comment: Thanks so much @larsks, it works perfectly. I've been looking for an explanation for the fact that I can't see mcserver in screens list for an hour, but the solution was just to write `sudo screen -list`.